# Java webapp in CentOS7 cannot connect to MSSQL server

Tags: java, sql-server-2008, jdbc, centos, firewall

My java web application connects to remote MSSQL server database by using JDBC. The address is a web URL: **https://mssql2008.server.com**. It works well on my PC. However, after I deployed it to Tomcat 9 on VPS CentOS 7. I got an error as follows:

> com.company.app.utils.DBConnection. nullcom.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection to the host mssql2008.server.com, port 1433 has failed. Error: "mssql2008.server.com. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.".

I have checked my MSSQL server and the port is opened and I can connect from my PC with only URL (without port). I also used PHP app on VPS for trying to connect but it also fails by **login timeout** ERROR

> SQLSTATE[HYT00]: [unixODBC][Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired

Is there anyone knows what happens? I think the problem is raised from my VSP CentOS. Do I need to install anything more on my VPS to let it can connect to MSSQL? or Is this a firewall problem?

Thank you in advance,

Comment: try running `telnet mssql2008.server.com 1433` on your centos server and see if you get any response. If you dont get any response then it is good to speak with your network admin

Comment: I have connected successfully by changing the domain name to IP address. But I don't know why I cannot connect to MSSQL by domain from VPS while it works well on my localhost.

Comment: In that case, see if your DNS resolves to proper IP by running the above command. You might also have custom entries against this domain name in your local `hosts` file.

Comment: It would seem that either a firewall is blocking you, or maybe your server is not running on port 1433, but on a different port, or it is is listening on port 1433, but not on an IP address accessible to you.

Comment: Thank everybody for helping me.